# Redirect 3rd level domain to 2nd level -- Will Analytics count traffic twice?

Tags: google-analytics, redirects, 301-redirect, google-ads

I am redirecting mycompany.com/product to promo.mycompany.com/product

My question is: Will Google Analytics count traffic twice under /product  ??

I am doing this because I create landing pages under third level domains but want Adwords traffic to see "mycompany.com/product"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't. As long as your analytics tracking code only sends 1 pageview it should just log it as one.

If you are concerned about this, you can try 302 redirecting first. Monitor your Analytics traffic and see if it has appeared to double. If it appears normal, you can then move to the 301 permanent. If it seems like the analytics data is somehow messed up after the 302, you can always 301 the subdomain back to the maindomain and you shouldn't lose any indexing or link juice from the redirect because it was 302 temporary and not 301 permanent.